# today's date, now function, macro variable

Tags: vba, function, date

I currently have an input box for a variable that changes everymonth:

r_mo = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Enter the reporting month as YYYYMM (Eg:201604). Errors in this entry will result in errors in the results.")

This prompts an input box which one has to manually enter into... However, I want to automate this process and eliminate the need for an input box. Isn't there a now function in vba that will automatically generate today's date.

From a now, or system function all I want to do is extract the year in four digits and the month in two digits.

So for example, if we're in decemeber 2016

```
Sub asasdas ()

  "Now function"
  r_mo = YYYYMM ' automatically updated from "now function"

End Sub
```

I appreciate any help you can give me and thank you so much all.

Comment: Perhaps you could work off this: http://www.classanytime.com/mis333k/sjdatetime.html, specifically the Now function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub GetMonthYear
    GetMonthYear = Year(Now) & Right("00" & Month(Now), 2)
End Sub
```

That'll do it.  Returns the Year portion of `Now()` and concatenates it to the Month portion of `Now()`.  Since Month will return a single digit for January to September, we wrap this by adding "00" to the Month and take the last two characters from the `Right`.  For "9" we create "009" and take the last two characters for "09".  For "10", we would create "0010" and take the last two characters for "10".

Comment: wow this is awesome, and the explanation is super helpful and clear. It makes everything better and more efficient for me going forward. Really, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Sub GetYearMonthDay()

Dim GetYearMonthDay As String

GetYearMonthDay = Year(Now) & "-" & Right("00" & Month(Now), 2) & "-" & Right("00" & Day(Now), 2)

MsgBox GetYearMonthDay

End Sub

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While your code snippet may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how your code snippet works improves its long-term value. Furthermore it doesn't seem to differ very much from the accepted answer...

Answer (score 0):

Please refer my answer given below

```
Sub UsingTheDateFunction()
    
    'this is the standard 6/3/2021 format
    
    Dim theDate As Date
    theDate = Date
    
    MsgBox theDate   
 
End Sub
```